# Hiding div element after X times using a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, cookies

i would like to hide a certain div element (lets say #bar1) after the user viewed it 5 times.
So basically it is a fixed positioned "bar" floating on the bottom of my website, with like options etc, i would like to hide it when a user seen it more then 5 times.

I presume it should be done using a cookie, i tried different methods but havent had any luck.

would appreciate i little guidance here.

i have wordpress based website

Answer (score 2):

Here is a site that explains a easy way of using cookies with a jquery plugin!

http://alexcican.com/post/set-cookies-javascript/

Comment: Hey there,thank you for the tutorial, but it only gives an example of how to hide an element after the first load, and though it was quite helpful, i still dodnt know how to show that element lets say 5 times instead of just once.

so what i need i to show the div 5 times to the same user, and then hide it.

will appreciate assistance on the matter as, i am not proficient with the whole cookie thing.

Comment: I'll try to put something together for you tonight